# after change tabBarItem TableViewController looks like black Screen

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbaritem

I have TableViewController with search bar, after update updateSearchResults it work and when I change TabBarItem and come back I have a black screen, may be somebody had this problem? How I understand, I should clear 
tableview in viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setNavigationBar()
        tableView.register(NewMessageTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        searchUsers.removeAll()
        searchController.searchBar.text = nil
        tableView.endUpdates()

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    }
```

[UITableView work like need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQsE1.png)

[Change TabBarItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKVk.png)

[TableView don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbcsK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
class SearchController: UISearchController {

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {        
        // to avoid black screen when switching tabs while searching
        isActive = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation about what your code does and why it answers the question. In this case, what is `isActive` actually doing and where to put this code?

Comment: Crazyrems!
Sorry, I'm newbie in StackOverflow
I find this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938239/tab-bar-and-uisearchcontroller-giving-black-screen